# Internet access from android emulator slow or unstable

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have enabled permissions for internet access, there are no proxies to deal with.  I find that though most of the time i can access the net from the browser in the emulator or from my application the access is very slow though I have high speed broadband connection.

My question is this - is there a setting in the emulator that is meant to simulate the speed of the internet connection and by default set to a lower value? if yes how do i change it.  if not why is the connection slow in the emulator.

Another problem is that this connection breaks often and I get page not found exception from both my application and the browser in the emulator.  this becomes ok once I restart he emulator.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting to [delay & throttle](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#netspeed) network I/O on the emulator but it defaults to full speed.

The problem is probably somewhere else since there is AFAIK no GUI / keyboard shortcut to trigger that delay and you would need to start the emulator from command line & specify these options.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in correct direction, found a way to change the speed and other options without having to restart the emulator. Maybe the net access is slow for some other reasons or maybe just some "emulation" problem

Answer (score 3):

I ended up trying this and seems to make a difference or maybe it is my imagination because the documentation says that the default is full speed and no latency.  But this does allow one to change the speed and also various other settings without having to restart the emulator.

1. Launch emulator and wait for it to load completely
2. From command line telnet to the emulator at the appropriate port for the AVD ex. `telnet localhost 5554`
3. This will bring you to the AVD console. here use the command `network speed full`.

More info - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

This can be done from commandline launch of emulator, but If you launch the emulator from avd manager and wish to change some settings while the emulator is running this may be useful

Comment: Aer there a way to test the emulators network speed? As if I run 'network status' ```
Current network status:
  download speed:          0 bits/s (0.0 KB/s)
  upload speed:            0 bits/s (0.0 KB/s)
  minimum latency:  0 ms
  maximum latency:  0 ms```